# Copying table from one Oracle DB to another via single-directed DBLink

Tags: database, oracle, database-migration, data-migration

There are two databases: A and B (11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 both). I've got a table in A and want to copy it as is to B. A has DBLink of B, and A user has privileges to create/drop tables in B. On the other hand, B has no DBLink of A and B user cannot even select from A.
I need to do it programmatically. No SQLPlus with its Copy allowed.
Is there any relevant solution?
P.S. Inserts to B via DBLink from A are possible but doesn't match my needs really well since tables are big and, as far as I understand, there's no way to get bulk operations work via DBLink.

Comment: so u need to copy table right ?

Comment: Absolutely. No changes, no other operations in between. Just copy.

Comment: Table Copy From One DB to Another DB from dblink.                              insert into local_table select * from table@database_link;                try this and let me know

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot do in this way. Local table is in B database, and, as I stated before, there's no ability to select from A database, since no DBLinks is published by A.

Comment: Can you not login to A and insert the data across the db link?

Comment: Do you mean inserting data directly with a set of INSERT statements? Yes, clearly, it will work. But here's the performance problem, since bulk insert doesn't work via BDLink.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE B as
SELECT * from A@DBLINK

Answer (score 0):

SELECT    'insert into '
       || table_name
       || ' select * from '
       || table_name
       || '@database_link;'
  FROM user_tables