# how to copy all tables from one database to another one using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two oracle connections and want to transfer the data/tables for a particular operational database from connection1(source) to connection2 (target). How would I do this?

Comment: If you insist on using sql, then look here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356236/copying-table-from-one-oracle-db-to-another-via-single-directed-dblink

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we do that by **Data Pump Export/Import** utilities, they are designed for such a purpose (moving data around). Here's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100); I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 2):

Backup one database either using:

- [`exp`/`imp`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm) (these are legacy utilities and you should probably use more modern ones);
- [`expdp`/`impdp`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100); or
- [`rman`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100)

Then restore it on the other database.